# Is it possible to attach a pdf generated by a view to an email message in django?

Tags: django, email, pdf

I'm using [this](https://github.com/nigma/django-easy-pdf) third party app for pdf generation.

In my view I've this code for creating the Pdf:

```
class artwork_catalog(PDFTemplateView):
    template_name = "someapp/sometemplate.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return super(artwork_catalog, self).get_context_data(
            pagesize="A4",
            title="My Title" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m/%Y'),
            artworks=ArtWork.objects.filter(public=True).order_by('year'),
            **kwargs
        )
```

I've the following Url for my view:

```
url(
        r"^mypdf.pdf$",
        artwork_catalog.as_view()
    ),
```

So I can access my Pdf at `localhost:8000/mypdf.pdf`.
Now I want to send this Pdf as attachment per email. I created a view but I can't bring it to work:

```
def order_catalog(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCatalogForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = 'Test'
            from_email = 'Test@Test.com'
            message = 'TESTTESTTESTTEST'
            recipient = form.cleaned_data['email']
            pdf = artwork_catalog # here I'd like to insert my Pdf
            try:
                mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_email, [recipient])
                mail.attach("MyPdf.pdf", pdf, "application/pdf")
                mail.send()
            except:
                return HttpResponse('Error')
            return redirect('/somewhere/')
    else:
        form = OrderCatalogForm()
    return render(request, 'someapp/order_catalog.html', {'form': form})
```

Any hints? best regards Manuel

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested by a solution, the following should work, using [easy_pdf.rendering.render_to_pdf](http://django-easy-pdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#easy_pdf.rendering.render_to_pdf):

```
from easy_pdf.rendering import render_to_pdf
...
pdf = render_to_pdf(
        'someapp/sometemplate.html',
        {
            'pagesize': "A4",
            'title': "My Title" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m/%Y'),
            'artworks' ArtWork.objects.filter(public=True).order_by('year')
        }
)
```